# Android how to log in to exchange server

Tags: android, authentication, exchange-server

I have been searching the web for many days, and I still have not found a good tutorial for beginners to log into an exchange server. I know there are protocols available e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=EXCHG.80).aspx, but I am hardly skilled enough to interpret.

I'm sure other beginners in app development would be curious as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ActiveSync, I have an ActiveSync client that works on Android. It logs into Exchange, and is able to perform GAL searches.

See [Corporate Addressbook](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/)

Comment: Hey thanks this is good! Configure.java, ActiveSynceManager.java... you reference alot of files. But which one do I concentrate on?

Comment: Look at the method  getExchangeServerVersion() in ActiveSyncManager.java. This is the method that connects to the Exchange server, queries for version information, and ensures that all works.

Comment: So everything from "private HttpResponse sendPostRequest" and after in ActiveSyncManager.java will not be needed?

Comment: And for now, it works! Gonna analyze the parts I have referenced and remove those unrequired... Do I have permission to use your code btw?

Comment: Yep feel free. It is Apache license, so do what you want. Please do let me know if you find any bugs though :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to access Exchange Mailboxes.

Additionally, there is a [managed API for Java](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi), but I'm not sure whether it will run on Android.

Comment: Ummm yeah I know about it, but I cant really make sense out of it atm. would be great if there is a simple tutorial for just the logging in aspect.